# replacing hot swap disk on same controller DL380

Tags: raid, storage, hp

I have a DL380 G9 server with RAID card and a few RAID LD setups. IT has some unassigned drives too. These are on the same SAS controller.

I know that when disk fails I can remove it and plug in a "new" disk from outside without any issues. What I do not know is if I can take out an unassigned drive from another slot (It has 12 populated slots), and put it in the place of bad disk.
Will it not confuse the controller to find the same disk (serial# xxx) which was in slot X a few seconds ago into this slot Y ?
I have not done it on live system, as I do not know how it will affect the array (Raid 6).

Anyone who has experienced this? I could not find anywhere on internet this particular operation.

```
# ssacli ctrl slot=3 show config

Smart Array P840 in Slot 3                (sn: xxxxxx)



   Internal Drive Cage at Port 1I, Box 1, OK



   Internal Drive Cage at Port 1I, Box 1, OK



   Internal Drive Cage at Port 2I, Box 2, OK


   Port Name: 1I

   Port Name: 2I

   Array A (SAS, Unused Space: 1  MB)

      logicaldrive 1 (8.19 TB, RAID 6, OK)

      physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS HDD, 3 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS HDD, 3 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SAS HDD, 3 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SAS HDD, 3 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:5 (port 1I:box 1:bay 5, SAS HDD, 3 TB, OK)


   Array B (SAS, Unused Space: 0  MB)

      logicaldrive 2 (2.73 TB, RAID 1, OK)

      physicaldrive 2I:2:1 (port 2I:box 2:bay 1, SAS HDD, 3 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:2:2 (port 2I:box 2:bay 2, SAS HDD, 3 TB, OK)


   Array C (SAS, Unused Space: 0  MB)

      logicaldrive 3 (2.73 TB, RAID 1, OK)

      physicaldrive 2I:2:3 (port 2I:box 2:bay 3, SAS HDD, 3 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:2:4 (port 2I:box 2:bay 4, SAS HDD, 3 TB, OK)

   Unassigned

      physicaldrive 1I:1:7 (port 1I:box 1:bay 7, SAS HDD, 3 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:8 (port 1I:box 1:bay 8, SAS HDD, 3 TB, OK)
```